# Exception in thread “main” org.web3d.x3d.sai.NotSupportedException Run time error in Java

Tags: java

I've been making progress on my Java application that loads and displays X3D models. However, now, I'm getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.web3d.x3d.sai.NotSupportedException: Default Browser implementation cannot create browser reference
    at org.web3d.x3d.sai.DefaultBrowserImpl.createComponent(DefaultBrowserImpl.java:53)
    at org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(BrowserFactory.java:185)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.<init>(Xj3DTest.java:42)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.main(Xj3DTest.java:56)
C:\Users\matt\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

My Java code is

```
package xj3dtest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.Browser;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DComponent;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DScene;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Xj3DTest extends JFrame {

    public Xj3DTest(String title) {

        super(title);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Setup browser parameters
        HashMap requestedParameters=new HashMap();
        requestedParameters.put("Antialiased",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("TextureQuality","medium");
        requestedParameters.put("PrimitiveQuality","medium");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_InterfaceType","SWING");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_NavbarShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_NavbarPosition","TOP");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationPosition","TOP");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationReadOnly",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ShowConsole",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_OpenButtonShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ReloadButtonShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_StatusBarShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_FPSShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ContentDirectory","CurrentDirectory");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_AntialiasingQuality","low");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_Culling_Mode", "frustum");

        System.setProperty("x3d.sai.factory.class", "org.xj3d.ui.awt.browser.ogl.X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl");
        X3DComponent x3dComponent = BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(requestedParameters);

        Browser browser = x3dComponent.getBrowser();

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add((javax.swing.JPanel)x3dComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        X3DScene scene = browser.createX3DFromURL(new String[] {"test.x3d"});

        browser.replaceWorld(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Xj3DTest frame = new Xj3DTest("Xj3D test");
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The `Jars` that I'm using are

```
aviatrix3d-all_3.1.0-nps.jar
commons-compress-1.10.jar
dis-enums.jar   
geoapi-nogenerics-2.1.0.jar
gluegen-rt-natives-linux-amd64.jar  
gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar
gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar
gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586.jar 
gluegen-rt.jar  
gnu-regexp-1.0.8.jar
gt2-main-2.4.4.jar  
gt2-metadata-2.4.4.jar
gt2-referencing-2.4.4.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
httpclient.jar  
imageloader_1.1.0.jar
j3d-org-all_3.0.0-nps.jar   
jai_codec.jar
jai_core.jar
jgeom-core.jar
jhall.jar   
jmf.jar 
joal-natives-linux-amd64.jar
joal-natives-macosx-universal.jar
joal-natives-windows-amd64.jar
joal-natives-windows-i586.jar
joal.jar
jogl-all-natives-linux-amd64.jar
jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal.jar   
jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar  
jogl-all-natives-windows-i586.jar   
jogl-all.jar    
js.jar   
jsr108-0.01.jar 
odejava-jni.jar 
odejava.jar
open-dis_4.08.jar   
openmali.jar    
smack.jar   
smackx.jar  
toxiclibscore.jar   
uri.jar 
vecmath.jar 
vlc_uri.jar
xj3d-sai.jar
```

I have Google Chrome as my default browser and I'm in dire need of help because it seems like I've been stuck on the same problem for ages. Thanks.

Comment: Have you googled ? http://objectmix.com/vrml/192048-%5Bx3d%5Dproblem-simplesaidemo.html

Comment: @RomainHippeau I have tried to google it, I google everything to see if I can find help before posting anything on here. Thanks for the link, I'll look through that now!

Comment: @RomainHippeau Thanks for the help with the link :)